# getNamedDispatcher on Appengine Java

Tags: java, google-app-engine, servlets, web.xml

Due to some unavoidable issues, I am attempting to forward request on Appengine Java from one servlet to another.  However, the "standard" config doesn't seem to work.  I have:

web.xml

```
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>class.of.MyServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
```

otherServlet.java

```
RequestDispatcher dispatcher = getServletContext().getNamedDispatcher("MyServlet");
dispatcher.forward(req, resp);
```

However, dispatcher is null (presumably because it can't find "MyServlet"), so I get an NPE.

This feels like a bug / non-standard implementation on the AppEngine side, but maybe I am missing something.

Comment: Hi Tad. Do you get an error? If so, could you please share it with us to have more context about it?

Comment: There isn't an error - just null returned from `getNamedDispatcher()` - presumably indicating that it can't find the servlet.

Comment: What is the servlet API version you are using? If you are using a different one than 3.1, you can try that

Comment: I'm using 2.5.  I'm working around it by just factoring out the shared code instead of forwarding the request, but I'll take a look.

Comment: are you using the java8 or java11 runtime? Could you include your `appengine-web.xml` or `app.yaml` according to your environment.
Also include your `web.xml` with the servlets mappings